# How to access declared template structure variables in SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, global-variables, swig

I am trying to generate a file of Python definitions from C++ using SWIG 3.0.5. These definitions are templated structures, defined in my toy `foo.h` as:

```
template<typename T> struct LimitDef
{
    T min;
    T max;
    int otherstuff;
    int etc;
}

namespace ProjectLimits
{
    const LimitDef<int>    Limit1 = {  -5, 100, 42,  0};
    const LimitDef<double> Limit2 = {-1.0, 1.0,  0, 42};
    ...
}
```

In my corresponding `foo.i` SWIG interface I have:

```
%module foo
%{
#include "foo.h"
%}

%include "foo.h"

%template(LimitDef_int) LimitDef<int>;
%template(LimitDef_double) LimitDef<double>;
```

Compiled to Python, I can access the newly instantiated template names (and create new `LimitDef_int` objects with no issue), and I can see the declared `Limit#` variables, but the types don't line up -- the already-declared vars are bare, inaccessible object pointers with no `__swig_getmethods__` etc:

```
>>> import foo
>>> newlim = foo.LimitDef_int()
>>> newlim.min = 5
>>> print newlim.min
5
>>> print newlim
<foo.LimitDef_int; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'LimitDef< int > *' at 0x17f2338> >
>>> foo.Limit1
<Swig Object of type 'LimitDef< int> *' at 0x17f2b30>
>>> print foo.Limit1.min
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SwigPyObject' object has no attribute 'min'
>>> dir(foo.Limit1.min)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__hex__', '__init__', '__int__', '__le__', '__long__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__oct__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'acquire', 'append', 'disown', 'next', 'own']
```

I've tried moving the `%template` directives to before `%include "foo.h"` so that the new instantiated template definitions are in place when the declared vars are parsed, but then I get `Error: Template 'LimitDef' undefined` when I try to build.

I've tried `%extend`ing the specific template types to provide accessors (as that's all I really need) e.g.:

```
%extend LimitDef<int> {
    int get_min() { return (*$self).min; }
};
```

But again, this applies only to the newly-created `LimitDef_int` type and its instances; `Limit1` etc. are unaffected (even when the `%extend` block is before `%include "foo.h"`).

I don't care so much about creating new instances as I am being able to access those existing `Limit#` variables. If at all possible I don't want to modify the source; my actual project file has 100+ such constants defined.

What am I missing that will allow me to have `foo.Limit1.min` return `-5`?

Comment: Try `foo.cvar.Limit1` ([36.3.3](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn16))

Comment: Wow, that did it. Very non-obvious since `Limit1` also exists on its own in the namespace of `foo`. I feel dumb nonetheless. Thanks @Oktalist!

Comment: SWIG is quite non-obvious in general. As this doesn't appear to be a duplicate, I turned my comment into an answer and tweaked the tags on the question to help others searching for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIG Manual - [36.3.3 [Python; Global variables]](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn16)

> To provide access to C global variables, SWIG creates a special object called `cvar` that is added to each SWIG generated module. Global variables are then accessed as attributes of this object.

So the proxy object for `Limit1` can be found at `foo.cvar.Limit1`.

See also [How C/C++ global variables are implemented in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18980096/1639256)